# Different behavior between Union and | in mypy when dealing with optionals

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

In the following two code examples, the first gives an error, while the latter does not. As I understand `type1 | type2` is supposed to be an alias for `Union[type1, type2]` in python3.10 (hence the `from __future__ import annotations`).

```
from __future__ import annotations

def f(a: int | str = None):
    pass
```

`error: Incompatible default for argument "a" (default has type "None", argument has type "Union[int, str]")`

```
from typing import Union

def f(a: Union[int, str] = None):
    pass
```

As of [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types), non-explicit optional is discouraged. Is this the correct behavior, or a bug?

- python = `3.9.1`
- mypy = `0.812`

Comment: Wouldn't the latter be `Optional[Union[int, str]]`?

Comment: It should be if PEP 484 were followed, but no error occurs when written this way.

Comment: Interesting find. `strict_optional` is set to `True` by default, so the error you are getting in first example is correct. I'd suggest to [open a new issue in mypy repo](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues), as it seems like a bug.